# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program to send emails but keep getting this error.

The code is:

```py
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

from email.mime.text import MIMEText


MY_ADDRESS = input('your email: ')

PASSWORD = input('your password: ')

emailadd = input('text file email addresses: ')

subject = input('text file containing subject  ')

body = input('text file containing body: ')


def getcontacts(filename):
    emails = []
    with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
        for a_contact in contacts_file:
            emails.append(a_contact)
    return emails


def readtemplate(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as template_file:
        return template_file.read()


def main():
    global contents, msg
    emails = getcontacts(emailadd)
    message_template = readtemplate(body)


    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(MY_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)


    for email in zip(emails):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        f = open(subject, 'r')
        if f.mode == 'r':
            contents = f.read()
        f.close()

        msg['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
        msg['To'] = email
        msg['Subject'] = contents

        msg.attach(MIMEText(message_template, 'plain'))

        s.send_message(msg)
        del msg

    s.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It shows no errors but when I run it I get this:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Comment: also when i entered the code as a question the formatting got a bit out of hand

Comment: Please refrain from adding begging messages to your questions, and **especially not in titles**. The upvotes you have thus far received seem to me to be unwarranted. Please use useful and informative titles, and remember that Stack Overflow is not a chat room. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of your `getcontacts` function the list of `emails` is a list of strings. When you do `for email in zip(emails)`, the `zip` puts every email-string in a 1-tuple. For example:

```
>>> x = ['foo', 'bar']  # these are your email addresses
>>> list(zip(x))
[('foo',), ('bar',)]
```

So you attempt to set the addressee to a tuple which doesn't make sense. Actually you can just leave out the `zip` and just do:

```
for email in emails:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was so confused as to why it showed that. Now there are no problems